# ¿Por qué mi aplicación de estudio de Android no se conecta a la base de datos en el servidor 000webhost.com?

Tags: php, java, mysql, android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en andriod studio, que está conectada a una base de datos en un servidor 000webhost.com, funcionaba correctamente, pero hoy, cuando quiero ingresar a través del inicio de sesión, me envía el siguiente error ...

```
    System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:119)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:176)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:119)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:176)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
        at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

¿por qué es? ¿Y cómo puedo resolverlo ?, estoy usando phpmyadmin, en un servidor gratuito de 000webhost, y es solo cuando paso el apk al  celular real. Les agradecería su respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

000WebHost tiene un problema, cada dia durante aproximadamente 60min va a tirar tu pagina y no podras acceder a ella, si haz visto que es a horas dispares (en la mañana o en la tarde) de forma indiscrimanda  entonces es debido a tu conexion, ya que el error que te manda es un TimeOut osea la conexion tardo mas de lo debido, ¿como lo puedes solucionar? la mejor manera es **no** conectar directamente tu aplicación al servidor, si no crear una API Rest que consuma los recurso de la BD y los libere en formato JSON, de ahi te conectas mediante request desde Android Studio y haces las peticiones con el metodo correspondiente (GET o POST).

Comment: Como se realiza lo que describes como solución? revisar [answer].

Comment: Se puede basar en (Rest Api Tutorial)[https://www.restapitutorial.com/]

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido.